# ¿Error al cargar estilos y seleccionar elementos de un modal dinamicamente?

Tags: php, bootstrap, modal

Estoy cargando una serie de datos con `PHP` en una tabla  desde la Base de Datos
y de acuerdo al dato seleccionado estoy abriendo un Modal que incluye apartados para agregar imágenes y demás.

Al seleccionar el primer dato de la lista se abre el modal y permite la selección de los elementos, pero al cerrar y abrir un segundo elemento ya no lo permite, se visualiza incorrectamente.

Codigo para generar la Tabla:

```
<div class="card">
    <table>
        <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>Nombre1</th>
            <th>Nombre1</th>
            <th>Nombre1</th>
            <th>Nombre1</th>
            <th>Nombre1</th>
            <th>Nombre1</th>
            <th>Nombre1</th>
            <th>Nombre1</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php if (!empty($result)): ?>
        <?php foreach ($result as $dato): ?>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <?php if ($dato->estatusSolicitudId == 17): ?>
                    <?php $numSolicitud = $dato->solicitudId ?>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal<?php echo $numSolicitud;?>">ACTIVAR</button> 
                        <!-- Inicia el Modal -->
                        <div id="modal<?php echo $numSolicitud; ?>" class="modal fade"  role="dialog">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <!-- Modal Header -->
                                    <div class="modal-header header-color">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                                            <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                                        </button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">TÉRMINOS Y CONDICIONES</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Modal Body -->
                                    <div class="modal-body body-color">
                                      <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <div class="card">
                                                <div class="header bg-teal text-center">
                                                    <label>CREDENCIAL PARTE FRONTAL</label>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                      <div id="preview"></div>
                                                  </div>
                                                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                    <form id="subir" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                                        <div class="form-group text-center">
                                                            <label for="imagen" class="custom-file-upload">
                                                                <i class="fa fa-image"></i> Seleccionar imagen
                                                            </label>
                                                            <input id="imagen" name="imagen" type="file"/>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </form>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="text-center" id="respuesta"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <div class="card">
                                            <div class="header bg-teal text-center">
                                                <label>CREDENCIAL PARTE POSTERIOR</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                  <div id="preview2"></div>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <form id="subir2" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                                    <div class="form-group text-center">
                                                        <label for="imagen2" class="custom-file-upload">
                                                            <i class="fa fa-image"></i> Seleccionar imagen
                                                        </label>
                                                        <input id="imagen2" name="imagen2" type="file" />
                                                    </div>
                                                </form>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="text-center" id="respuesta2"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="card">
                                      <div class="card-body">
                                        <h5 class="card-title text-center">Informacion</h5>
                                        <!-- Mas Informacion-->
                                        <label><?php echo $numSolicitud; ?></label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>   
                        <form role="form" id="formulario">
                            <div class="form-check check-margin">
                                <input type="checkbox"  id="checkAceptar" name="checkAceptar" value="10">
                                <label class="form-check-label condition-color" for="checkAceptar">He leído y acepto los términos y condiciones.</label>
                                <p class="statusCheck"></p>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Modal Footer -->
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"  id="btn-cerrar" data-dismiss="modal">CERRAR</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btn-ingresar">ACEPTAR</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Termina el Modal -->
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="label label-danger" >No activada</span>
    </td>
<?php else: ?>
    <td>
        <span class="label label-success">ACTIVADA</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php $poliza= $dato->solicitudId;
        $encrypt = $funciones->encrypt($poliza);?>
        <a href="accountStatus.php?poliza=<?php echo $encrypt; ?>" >
            <i class="material-icons">monetization_on</i>
        </a>
    </td>
<?php endif ?>
</tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="bg-danger text-center" colspan="8">No se encontraron datos.</td>
    </tr>
<?php endif ?>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

CSS para visualizar las imagenes:

```
input[type="file"] {
        display: none;
    }
    .custom-file-upload {
        border: 0px solid #ccc;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 12px 12px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    #preview {
        /*border:2px solid #ddd;*/
        padding:5px;
        border-radius:2px;
        background:#444343;
        max-width:200px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

    #preview img {
        width:100%;
        display:block;
    }
    #preview2 {
        /*border:1px solid #ddd;*/
        padding:5px;
        border-radius:2px;
        background:#444343;
        max-width:200px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

    #preview2 img {
        width:100%;
        display:block;
    }
```

Archivo JS:

```
$(document).on('ready',function(){
        $("#preview").hide();
        document.getElementById("imagen").onchange = function(e) {
            let reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(){
                $("#preview").show();

                let preview = document.getElementById('preview'),
                image = document.createElement('img');

                image.src = reader.result;

                preview.innerHTML = '';
                preview.append(image);
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
        }
        $("#preview2").hide();
        document.getElementById("imagen2").onchange = function(e) {
            let reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(){
                $("#preview2").show();

                let preview = document.getElementById('preview2'),
                image = document.createElement('img');

                image.src = reader.result;

                preview.innerHTML = '';
                preview.append(image);
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
        }
    });
```

[Imagen Correcta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KnLH.png)  e [Imagen incorrecta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZfzl.png)

¿Alguna forma de solucionarlo?

Comment: Tienes mal planteado tu solución, no deberias crear el modal en un ciclo cuando vas a mostrar practicamente lo mismo

Comment: De hecho se mostrara información de cada elemento seleccionado.

Comment: seria mas fácil ayudarte si tuvieras un ejemplo en jsfiddle o cualquier similar.

Comment: Veo varios detalles, **1)** Usa `foreach():`, `endforeach;`, `if:` y `endif;` para tener una estructura más clara. Te darás cuenta que falta cerrar el `if`. **2)** `if($dato->solicitud==17)` solo deja pasar las que tienen el número 17, ¿Esto es correcto y hay más con este número? **3)** He probado el código tal cual alimentado con un objeto y funcionan todos los _modal_ y los _Ckeckbox_ son operativos.

Comment: @OscarR ya he editado la pregunta y he agregado lo que mencionas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya lo he solucionado pasando como referencia el numero generado mediante el `foreach` y agregandolo al data-id de esta forma:

```
<a href="#solicitud"  data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?php echo $numSolicitud ?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">ACTIVAR</button></a>
```

Y abrir el Modal usando eventos Bootstrap:

```
    $('#solicitud').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
/*....*/      
});
```

[Eventos Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-events)

Con respecto al Modal lo ubique fuera del Ciclo después de tabla con la finalidad de no crear un modal por cada iteracion y así mismo evitar la perdida de estilos que me estaba causando.

```
......
</tbody>
</table>
<!-- Inicia el Modal -->
<div id="solicitud" class="modal fade"  role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
......
```

> **Colocación de marcado modal** 
>   Siempre trate de colocar un código HTML modal en una posición de nivel superior en su documento para
>   evitar que otros componentes afecten la apariencia y / o funcionalidad
>   del modal.

[Documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals)